# logstash parse dynamically json to add new fields in the output

Tags: json, logstash, logstash-configuration

I have the following JSON INPUT:

```
{
    "ts": "1459504800000",
    "data": "30.7",
    "sid": "1"
}
```

Whit this filter:

```
filter {
    mutate {
            convert => { 
            "data" => "float"
            "ts" => "integer" 

        }

    }

    date { 
        match => [ "ts", "UNIX_MS"]
            target => "ts_date"
    }
}
```

I get the following result:

```
{
            "ts" => 1459504800000,
          "data" => 30.7,
           "sid" => "1",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-04-21T14:29:54.241Z",
          "type" => "redis-input",
       "ts_date" => "2016-04-01T10:00:00.000Z"
}
```

I would like to add a new field in the result composed dynamically with `"data"` and `"sid"` parameters values (1 and 30.7) of the input. This field should be somthing like `"somestring"+"1" => 30.7`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what add_field is for.  For tasks like this that are unrelated to other filters, I'd use it in mutate:

```
mutate {
    add_field => { "something%{sid}" => "%{data}" }
}
```

The value would be a string at this point.  If you want it to be numeric, you'd need a second mutate using the convert function.

Comment: Thanks @Alain. Do you know how could I parse the data type of the "%{data}" to float?

Comment: Yes, "If you want it to be numeric, you'd need a second mutate using the convert function."

Comment: Something like mutate `{ convert => { "something%{sid}" => "float"}}`?